# How to set TextField property as small and fullwidth globally

Tags: material-ui

Wanted to set material ui textfield properties globally both - size="small" and fullwidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use theming to set globals [documentation here](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/).
Go [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) to see how to apply a theme [

Your example would look like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  props: {
    TextField: {
      fullWidth: true,
      size: "small"
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  props: {
    MuiTextField: {
      size: "small",
      fullWidth: true
    },  
  }
});

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```